# Create stream with FFmpeg from different ip

Tags: linux, networking, interface, ffmpeg

I need to create HLS stream with FFmpeg from **different ip**. It's like *--bind-address* in wget command. i have **2 network interface** i need choose which i want and process command in **terminal**.

Comment: If you are outputting to UDP, you can use something like udp://192.168.1.10:8000?localaddr=192.168.1.3

Comment: localaddr only for UDP i need to stream HLS. I will edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i use **http_proxy**.

*http_proxy
set HTTP proxy to tunnel through e.g. http://example.com:1234*

http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html